# Facebook SDK for .NET Core

Tags: facebook, asp.net-core, facebook-c#-sdk, .net-core, facebooksdk.net

Up until now I've been using Facebook SDK for .NET by https://hackerapp.com/

I want to upgrade my project to ASP.NET Core, but I see that their library doesn't have support for .NET Core - nor do they mention about upcoming support for .NET Core.

I can write an HTTP wrapper against Facebook API - but that seems like over-complicating my app - when there's a nice library that is made just for that.

Does anyone know about Facebook SDK for .NET Core?

Comment: Badly Need a .Net Core library for Facebook.

Comment: https://github.com/developer82/FacebookCore

Answer (score 9, accepted):

So after not finding a solution, I've decided to develop my own some time ago. You may find here: https://github.com/developer82/FacebookCore

Answer (score 4):

I don't know why you got a -1, but I am facing the same issue. 
Therefore for now I am going to use the OAUTH provided by .Net then direct requests to the graph API...

The other option I know would be to have a look there:
https://github.com/Microsoft/winsdkfb

And there for some more advanced features:
https://github.com/Microsoft/UWPCommunityToolkit/tree/dev/Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.Services/Services/Facebook

I am thinking about porting a SDK to .Net Core, but that may be too much work!

Comment: I don't know about -1 wither. But FB SDK is not the only thing lacking support that I  found that I need - PushSharp also doesn't have support for .NET Core, ReshSharp as well... That's kind of disappointing because .NET Core has so much potential and it is faster - but if the community doesn't port libraries then it's domed to failure.

Comment: I didn't know these libraries, nice one, I will have a look.
I will check if they are portable to core :) (PushSharp)
However for ReshSharp, I prefer ASP services :)

Comment: I can always find a way to live without one library or the other - just a lot of work. PushSharp however is a must for me - I developed direct interface against APNS and GCM in the past - nightmare!